# Parsing a string to dict with Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
/acommand foo='bar' msg='Hello World!' -debugMode
```

or like this:

```
/acommand
foo='bar'
msg='Hello, World!'
-debugMode
```

How can I parse this string to a dict and a list like this:

```json
{"command": "/acommand", "foo": "bar", "msg": "Hello World!"}

["-debugMode"]
```

I've tried to use `string.split` to parse it but seems it's not feasible.

`argparse` seems like that it was born for the command line interface so it doesn't apply.

How to achieve this with Python? Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html allows you to define your own prefix char - i.e. give it '/' instead of `-`

Comment: Your result `dict` is not valid python syntax. How would you reference `["-debugMode"]`?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to move the list out of the dict

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
s = "/acommand foo='bar' msg='Hello World!' -debugMode"
debug = [s.split(" ")[-1]]
s_ = "command=" + ' '.join(s.split(" ")[:-1]).replace("'","")
d = dict(x.split("=") for x in s_.split(" ",2))
print (d)
print (debug)
```

{'command': '/acommand', 'foo': 'bar', 'msg': 'Hello World!'},

['-debugMode']

> 

Comment: This is incredibly brittle. It works for this very specific case but what happens if `foo='Hello World'`?

Comment: @Axe319 In that case the user should specify more detailed what he wants. None of us can know what combinations are expected nor write a solution that covers everything for a task like this. Do you agree?